# Saving credentials with sharedpreferences

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to save user credentials using sharedpreferences, i am doing it by this way but it is not working

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public EditText UserName;
    public EditText Password;
    public Button mButton;
    public String user_name;
    public String pass_word;
    public CheckBox mCheckSavePassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textUserName);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPassword);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        mCheckSavePassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkSavePassword);

        mCheckSavePassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkSavePassword);
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = preferences.edit();                    
        preferencesEditor.putString("prefUserName", user_name);                 
        if(mCheckSavePassword.isChecked()) {
            preferencesEditor.putString("prefPassword", pass_word);
        }                   
        preferencesEditor.putBoolean("prefSavePassword", mCheckSavePassword.isChecked());
        preferencesEditor.apply();
    }
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: because when i re-enter again, requires fill up credentials

Comment: Post the code you're using to read the preference values so we can see what isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving null values—when your activity is first created, `user_name` and `pass_word` have not been initialized.

`onCreate` is where you should be ***reading*** the values of these preferences and updating the EditTexts with those values. Saving should be done as a result of some user interaction, such as when a button is pressed.